# SSIS Data Transfer from Oracle to SQL Server - Check if table exists, if not create it

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, ssis, data-transfer

DEV Tool - Visual Studio 2015 Update 2

Essentially, what I want to do is the following within a SSIS package:

1. Drop all existing tables within the database
2. Transfer data from multiple Oracle database tables to a SQL Server table

   ```
   INSERT INTO SQL_DB_TABLE
       SELECT * 
       FROM ORACLE_DB.TABLE
   ```

The first task in my sequence container is to drop all of the tables in a SQL task. Then, for each Oracle table, I have a Data Flow Task. Within each task, I have an ODBC Source that is a `SELECT * FROM ORACLE_DB.TABLE`. I add a ‘Destination Assistant’ then click on ‘New’, to create the table based on the Oracle table structure.

[image]

Add the table name I want then click ‘OK’.  At this point, the new table is added to the SQL Server.

[image]

I am looking for a way to replicate the ‘NEW’ (create the table in SQL Server) process for each Oracle table every time I run the sequence container. The caveat is that the columns in the Oracle tables may change, which is why I have to recreate them each time.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with DataFlows.  DataFlows have to have consistent meta-data.   In other words, the columns have to stay the same each time the same dataflow runs.

Even though the query is SELECT *, you have to set up the columns that will be output by the source, and if those columns ever change on a subsequent run, the dataflow will break.

The only way I can think of to do this in a static SSIS package is with a script task.   And it would be a daunting one to write.

A better way might be to create packages dynamically with BiMLScript.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do it, but would be lots of script tasks.  I would select the table's column metadata from oracle into a package variable, and then build a "create table" statement dynamically and an "execute SQL task" from variable.

```
select column_name,data_type,data_length,nullable 
from user_tab_cols c where table_name = '{your table}'
```

There would need to be some work to determine the relation between the oracle data types and the SQL equivalents.

The issue is the downstream validation - you would not be able to use a traditional destination object - rather a script component as a destination, which will be slow and hard to maintain - assuming you have column names and table names in variables, shouldn't be impossible.